# Easier way to enable verbose logging

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to add a debug print statement test, if I enable `--verbose` from the command line and if I have the following in the script.

```
logger.info("test")
```

I went through the following questions, but couldn't get the answer...

- [How to implement the --verbose or -v option into a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980042/how-to-implement-the-verbose-or-v-option-into-a-python-script)
- [Python logging - Is there something below DEBUG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042919/python-logging-is-there-something-below-debug)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You need to combine the wisdom of the [Argparse Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) with [Python's Logging HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html). Here's an example...

```
> cat verbose.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import logging

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='A test script for http://stackoverflow.com/q/14097061/78845'
)
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="increase output verbosity",
                    action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.verbose:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('Only shown in debug mode')
```

Run the help:

```
> ./verbose.py -h
usage: verbose.py [-h] [-v]

A test script for http://stackoverflow.com/q/14097061/78845

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  increase output verbosity
```

Running in verbose mode:

```
> ./verbose.py -v
DEBUG:root:Only shown in debug mode
```

Running silently:

```
> ./verbose.py   
>
```

Comment: // , I can confirm that this works. How "store_true" works, however, is still a bit of a mystery.

Comment: This means that, if the option is specified, assign the value `True` to `args.verbose`. Not specifying it implies `False`.

Answer (score 178):

I find both `--verbose` (for users) and `--debug` (for developers) useful.  Here's how I do it with `logging` and `argparse`:

```
import argparse
import logging

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-d', '--debug',
    help="Print lots of debugging statements",
    action="store_const", dest="loglevel", const=logging.DEBUG,
    default=logging.WARNING,
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-v', '--verbose',
    help="Be verbose",
    action="store_const", dest="loglevel", const=logging.INFO,
)
args = parser.parse_args()    
logging.basicConfig(level=args.loglevel)
```

So if `--debug` is set, the logging level is set to `DEBUG`.  If `--verbose`, logging is set to `INFO`.  If neither, the lack of `--debug` sets the logging level to the default of `WARNING`.

Comment: There's one catch: `logging` by default prints everything to stderr and you really want separate your normal program output (the one from `--verbose`) from dev-only (the one from `--debug`)

Comment: @MichałGóral: That sounds like a good point.  Can I use `logging.basicConfig` to send `info()` messages to stdout and `debug()` messages to stderr?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: To do that you'll have to use several [handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#handlers). Here's the example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16066513/1088577

Comment: @MatthewLeingang When the output is a console/terminal it's usually better to send all messages to stderr. Sending them to stdout typically makes it more difficult to use your program in a unix pipeline. The rule of thumb for me is stdout -> program output, stderr -> program messages.

Comment: I don't really like this approach because it pollutes the arguments namespace with additional arguments. Also, the processing logic is kind of convoluted. If I had to use this approach, I'd put the default loglevel as a global, and would wrap the verbose/debug arguments in a mutual exclusion group (see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion).

Comment: @m000 (1): fair point, I think Michał's linked example addresses that.  (2) I wasn't aware of the mutual exclusion group feature.  If I were rewriting this answer now I would use it.

Comment: This solution worked for me, except for some reason I had to use `logging.getLogger().setLevel(args.loglevel)` instead of `.basicConfig`

Comment: @Dwigt I wonder if the API has changed in the 9 years since I wrote this. I was probably using 3.2 then.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I'm sure it has :) I haven't confirmed this, but I read elsewhere that it could have something to do with the logger being declared already depending on how your code is setup, so calling `basicConfig` on it doesn't change anything and you need to reference the existing logger. Either way, great solution!

Answer (score 81):

Here is a more concise method, that does bounds checking, and will list valid values in help:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is a demo.')
parser.add_argument("-l", "--log", dest="logLevel", choices=['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL'], help="Set the logging level")

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.logLevel:
    logging.basicConfig(level=getattr(logging, args.logLevel))
```

Usage:

```
demo.py --log DEBUG
```

Comment: There's no need for `getattr`: `level=logging.getLevelName(args.logLevel)`

Comment: Even better is to add `default='INFO'` to `add_argument()` as well as `(default: %(default)s)` to the help text, then delete the `if args.logLevel` and always call `basicConfig()`. Then the user can know what the default value will always be.

Answer (score 38):

Another variant would be to count the number of `-v` and use the count as an index to the a `list` of `logging` levels:

```
import argparse
import logging
    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='count', default=0)
args = parser.parse_args()

levels = [logging.WARNING, logging.INFO, logging.DEBUG]
level = levels[min(args.verbose, len(levels) - 1)]  # cap to last level index
logging.basicConfig(level=level)
    
logging.debug('debug message')
logging.info('info message')
logging.warning('warning message')
logging.error('error message')
logging.critical('critical message')
```

- If no option is provided then `logging.WARNING` is selected.
- If one option `-v` is provided then `logging.INFO` is selected.
- If two options `-v -v` (or `-vv`) or more are provided then `logging.DEBUG` is selected.

Comment: Nice! Just remember to run your script as `python script.py -v [other_args]`. If you run `python -v script.py` (`-v` before the script), you will get a lot of debug output from the Python interpreter itself, but not from your script. (Not a problem with the answer, just a warning to other readers).

Comment: Good one! This is the most flexible (multiple logging levels), clean (doesn't pollute the arguments namespace) and intuitive (used by several other tools) solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only affects the `logging` (which is `stderr`) and not the communication with the user (`stdout` usually via `print()`). Also note the [Python-Docs about when to use logging and when to use print](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging). IMHO `-v` shouldn't affect the logging level but only the `stdout` output.

Answer (score 8):

You can explicity specify a level as an integer after the `-v` flag:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", const=1, default=0, type=int, nargs="?",
                    help="increase verbosity: 0 = only warnings, 1 = info, 2 = debug. No number means info. Default is no verbosity.")
args = parser.parse_args()

logger = logging.getLogger()
if args.verbose == 0:
    logger.setLevel(logging.WARN) 
elif args.verbose == 1:
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) 
elif args.verbose == 2:
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to enable logging.DEBUG level for a script you don't want to (or cannot) edit, you can customize your startup:

```
jcomeau@aspire:~$ python -c "import site; site._script()"
[snip]...
USER_BASE: '/home/jcomeau/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/jcomeau/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
jcomeau@aspire:~$ mkdir -p ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
jcomeau@aspire:~$ vi ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usercustomize.py
```

enter the following:

```
import os, logging
if os.getenv('DEBUGGING'):
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
```

then you can just:

```
jcomeau@aspire:~$ mkdir -p /tmp/some/random/
jcomeau@aspire:~$ echo 'import logging; logging.debug("test")' >> /tmp/some/random/script.py
jcomeau@aspire:~$ DEBUGGING=1 python /tmp/some/random/script.py 
DEBUG:root:test
```

from Paul Ollis at http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201001/running_code_at_python_startup.html

---

2017-07-18: I've since switched to a different method:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG if __debug__ else logging.INFO)
```

what this does is, if you're running without optimization (as in `python script.py`) you get the DEBUG-level stuff, whereas if you run with `python -OO script.py` you don't. no environment variables to set.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another take on having argparse count the -v option to increase verbosity up two levels from the default WARNING to INFO (-v) to DEBUG (-vv). This does not map to the constants defined by `logging` but rather calculates the value directly, limiting the input:

```
print( "Verbosity / loglevel:", args.v )
logging.basicConfig( level=10*(3-max(0,min(args.v,3))) )
logging.debug("debug") # 10
logging.info("info") # 20
logging.warning("warning") # 30 - The default level is WARNING, which means that only events of this level and above will be tracked
logging.error("error") # 40
logging.critical("critical") # 50
```

Comment: Note the argparse argument needs `default=0`, otherwise you'll get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`. Or add `args.v or 0` above...

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) and [Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

```
 import argparse
 import logging
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 parser.add_argument("--log", dest='loglevel', help="desired loglevel", default="WARNING")
 args = parser.parse_args()
 
 # assuming loglevel is bound to the string value obtained from the
 # command line argument. Convert to upper case to allow the user to
 # specify --log=DEBUG or --log=debug 
 numeric_level = getattr(logging, args.loglevel.upper(), None)
 if not isinstance(numeric_level, int):
     raise ValueError('Invalid log level: %s' % args.loglevel)
 logging.basicConfig(level=numeric_level)
```