# Python logging split between stdout and stderr

Tags: python, logging, stderr, python-logging

Is it possible to have python logging messages which are INFO or DEBUG to go to stdout and WARNING or greater to go to stderr?

Answer (score 74):

This seems to do what I want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging


class InfoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno in (logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO)


logger = logging.getLogger("__name__")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

h1 = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
h1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h1.addFilter(InfoFilter())
h2 = logging.StreamHandler()
h2.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

logger.addHandler(h1)
logger.addHandler(h2)
```

Comment: Creating a filter class is actually not necessary. You can also pass a callable: `h1.addFilter(lambda record: record.levelno <= logging.INFO)`

Comment: @Schiavini, for what it's worth, your modification doesn't seem to work in Python 2.7.15 - `logging/__init__.py:Filterer.filter()` raises an error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'filter'`. The code as-written does work in this version of Python.

Comment: I've only tested with python 3. That probably means you'll need the class as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Side effect: consecutive log messages may get displayed in the wrong order (e.g. when combining stdout and stderr in the console). I guess this is due to the fact that both streams may use independent buffers. I couldn't find a way to fix this yet.

Comment: Typically, you would use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` (without the quotation marks) to use the name of the module.

Answer (score -2):

I thought this would help: [`Handler.setLevel(lvl)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setLevel)

*Sets the threshold for this handler to lvl. Logging messages which are less severe than lvl will be ignored. When a handler is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all messages to be processed).*

But now I see that it wouldn't do what you want (split INFO/DEBUG from WARNING/ERROR)

That being said, you could write a custom handler (a class extending `logging.StreamHandler` for example), and overwrite the [`Handler.handle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.handle) method.

Comment: This is not enough to *stop* WARNING messages to be logged to stdout *still*.

Comment: A filter would probably be better.

Comment: Correct, I noticed it after posting my answer. Fixed now.