# Project/Multiple Class Verbose Mode Python

Tags: python, debugging

I'm wondering what the simplest way to enable debugging/verbose mode outputs in a project that involves multiple classes/files. The answer given here: [Easier way to enable verbose logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097061/easier-way-to-enable-verbose-logging) works well in a single script but what might be the best implementation across multiple classes?

I've thought to use the Singleton design pattern to set a single instance of a `"Debugger"` which will have a `Debugger.log("message")`. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already exists. this is `logging.root` which is a `logging.Logger` instance. You just need to set it up before using it. A simple example:

```
>>> import logging
>>>
>>> logging.root.setLevel('INFO')
>>> logging.root.info('Info message')
INFO:root:Info message
```

The logging functions for the root logger are also available from the `logging` module directly:

```
>>> logging.info('Info message')
INFO:root:Info message
```

For a full reference on how to setup a logger see [the official python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/logging.html).

Comment: Ah perfect I should have looked there first. Thank you.