# What does '--log=INFO' mean in Python Logging HOWTO

Tags: python, logging

I read the [Python Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file), and there is a description I don't understand:

> If you want to set the logging level from a command-line option such
>   as:
>
> ```
> --log=INFO
> ```
>
> and you have the value of the parameter passed for `--log` in some variable *loglevel*, you can use:
>
> ```
> getattr(logging, loglevel.upper())
> ```
>
> to get the value which you’ll pass to [`basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) via the *level* argument.

What does it mean? There is no example, it would be nice if someone could give one.

Can I set the logging level like this?

```
logging --log=INFO
```

Comment: Not an answer to this particular question, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097061/easier-way-to-enable-verbose-logging

Comment: Thank you,I got it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assumption is that you are using something like `argparse` to define command line arguments:

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--log")

args = p.parse_args()
loglevel = args.log
```

The argument to the `--log` option should then be one of the level constants defined in the `logging` module; `getattr(logging, loglevel.upper())` would then be a way to get that value for a string.