# logging.basicConfig in Python won't work if calling logging.info() before declaring

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Based on this answer, [Easier way to enable verbose logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097061/easier-way-to-enable-verbose-logging)

Let's take this Python script.

```
import argparse
import logging


def main():
    import argparse
    import logging

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='A test script for http://stackoverflow.com/q/14097061/78845'
    )
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="increase output verbosity",
                        action="store_true")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.verbose:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    logging.info('Shown in debug and info mode')
    logging.debug('Only shown in debug mode')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info('Starting script!')
    main()
```

Running this script from terminal as `python -m verbose -v` won't print anything.

If you comment the line `logging.info('Starting script!')` from the file as in

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #logging.info('Starting script!')
    main()
```

then logging works as expected.

It looks like an attempt to call a `logging.info()` before `basicConfig` is defined will fully disable any logging.

Is it a bug in `logging` or a common gotcha and why does this happen?

I am on Python 3.6.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) documentation: (Emphasis mine)

> ```
>  logging.basicConfig(**kwargs)
> ```
>
> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root
>   logger.
>
> **The functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and
>   critical() will call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are
>   defined for the root logger.**
>
> This **function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured** for it.

So basically your first call to `logging.info` made some automatic configuration. Your later configuration attempt silently failed because of the automatic configuration that already happend.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. Cannot say that suppressing the failed attempt to initialize `basicConfig` again is helpful. I've tested adding `logging.warning('Warning')` in the function and it was printed. I assume that the default configuration will log anything more severe than `warning`? Made some tests and printed `error` and `critical` as well. Is it (what would be this default configuration) documented?

Comment: Can the `force=True` argument be used to go around this?

Comment: ok, this explains why it does not work in GCP functions!

Answer (score 7):

Don't use basicConfig to change the level. Use `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to change the level on the root logger. One can do this on any logger or handler as well.