# how to set logging level from command line

Tags: python, logging, argparse

I'm using argparse to get the logging level from the command line and then passing it as input for logging.basicConfig. However, the way I'm trying to implement this is not working. Any suggestion?

Desire behavior, from command line:

```
python main.py -log=DEBUG
```

Desire output

```
DEBUG:__main__: Debug is working
```

Code

```
import logging
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-log", "--log", nargs='+', help="Provide logging level. Example --log debug'")

log_level = parser.parse_args().log
log_level = 'logging.'+log_level[0]
print(log_level)
logging.basicConfig(level=log_level)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 
logger.debug(' Debug is working')
```

Comment: Why do you put `nargs='+'`, the user have to choose only one level, the default notation is that your parameter is optional ([python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#required))?

Comment: @ndclt you are right, nargs='+' is not required and was the main reason why I was getting a list as input.

Comment: I often recommend `args = parser.parse_args()` followed by `print(args)`.  The gives you a clear(er) idea of what the parser has done for you.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097061

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks a lot! That was helpful! You inspired me and now my `args = parser.parse_args()` is followed by `for arg, val in vars(args).items(): print(f"{arg:17s} : '{val}'")`. This gives me an even clearer idea of what the parser has done for me !

Answer (score 25):

The `basicConfig` function can take a string argument for `level`, and it will check its validity for you, so the code can be much simpler than BarryPye's answer.

```
import argparse
import logging

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument( '-log',
                     '--loglevel',
                     default='warning',
                     help='Provide logging level. Example --loglevel debug, default=warning' )

args = parser.parse_args()

logging.basicConfig( level=args.loglevel.upper() )
logging.info( 'Logging now setup.' )
```

Comment: This would work better (more readable than replicating the logging levels in a local dict), but I would recommend limiting the possible inputs in this case, with `choices=logging._nameToLevel.keys()`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, and I know this wasn't explicitly stated in the question, but while `basicConfig` works fine for the main script, it does nothing to modify logger levels in imported packages, which I assume most non-trivial uses of logging would want to do.  I tried just this, hardcoded logging.INFO once in basic.Config.  Main got INFO, but package stayed at WARNING.  Changed to ERROR and main was at ERROR. package stayed at WARNING.

Comment: Even if `basicConfig` did affect logging levels on packages, the problem is that the `logger = logging.get_logger(__name__)` on the packages will fire as you import those packages, which is before you hit argparse/optparse parsing, provided you respect PEP 8 to import packages before running code.  I don't mean to criticize this answer, which I am upvoting, but `logging` seems to always lose me in the weeds.

Answer (score 17):

Putting these combinations together, allowing the user to name the level with upper or lower case, allowing only one level to be specified, and picking the explicit level from a dictionary with a default to the WARNING level:

```py
import argparse
import logging
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-log", 
    "--log", 
    default="warning",
    help=(
        "Provide logging level. "
        "Example --log debug', default='warning'"),
)

options = parser.parse_args()
levels = {
    'critical': logging.CRITICAL,
    'error': logging.ERROR,
    'warn': logging.WARNING,
    'warning': logging.WARNING,
    'info': logging.INFO,
    'debug': logging.DEBUG
}
level = levels.get(options.log.lower())
if level is None:
    raise ValueError(
        f"log level given: {options.log}"
        f" -- must be one of: {' | '.join(levels.keys())}")
logging.basicConfig(level=level)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: You can check the user enters a proper log level using the `ArgumentParser.add_argument()` `choices` input parameter. It allows you to provide a list of the possible inputs for that command line argument, and argparse handles the errors when the user enters the wrong argument.

Comment: About `levels`, you can use `logging.getLevelName(options.log.upper())` and check if result is `int`.
From py3.11 you can use also `logging.getLevelNamesMapping()`

Answer (score 3):

The level should be a variable from `logging` not a string, `logging.DEBUG` for example. I think you have to create a dict matching the given argument and the logging variable:

```py
level_config = {'debug': logging.DEBUG, 'info': logging.INFO} # etc.
log_level = level_config[parser.parse_args().log[0].lower()]
```

You can also add `choices=['debug', 'info', 'warning']` in your `add_argument` call.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and got the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: I forgot a `[0]` after the log (I edit my post). But I think blues solution is more elegant than mine.

Comment: Nicely done. This one should be selected as answer!

Comment: As of Python 3.2 you can specify level as a string

Answer (score 1):

`log_level = 'logging.'+log_level[0]` this just makes the string `'logging.DEBUG'` which is not something that basicConfig understands. what it want's is the `logging.DEBUG` constant which you can get by `getattr(logging, log_level[0])`. Newer versions of python actually accept the textual representation as well and you can just pass in `'DEBUG'` as level.

Comment: Hi @blues, after trying log_level = getattr(logging, log_level[0]),
logging.basicConfig(level=log_level) I got the following error     raise TypeError("Level not an integer or a valid string: %r" % level)
TypeError: Level not an integer or a valid string: <function info at 0x7ffff6cf0378>

Comment: My guess would be that you did not capitalize the argument. Make sure to supply the argument as `-log=DEBUG` and not `-log=debug`. Or call `.upper()` on it.